# More than one line in mode-line?

Tags: mode-line

I would like to make modeline display all information not in one line but in two - for example first for cursor info, buffer, file, git and flycheck, and on second line - modes info (major and minor modes). Is it doable somehow? I googled bindings.el and emacs C source code and wasn't lucky to find where this line number for modeline could be possible changed, does anybody can help with this? Thx.

Comment: In addition to the suggestion of wasamasa below, you may also wish to consider putting one-half of the information in the `header-line-format` and the other one-half in the `mode-line-format`.  Some people also use the `frame-title-format` as an additional location to store useful information.

Comment: Big thanks for `header-line`, it made my day, I found additional package path-headerline-mode that make lots of what I wanted to eliminate from modeline, thx a lot!

Comment: You might be able to do this with svg mode-lines (I'm not sure). The [svg-mode-line-themes](https://github.com/sabof/svg-mode-line-themes) package and the [ocodo-svg-modelines](https://github.com/ocodo/ocodo-svg-modelines) packages are examples of what you can do with SVG.

Answer (score 8):

I'm afraid this is generally not possible as newlines in `mode-line-format` are interpreted verbatim and appear as `^J` or `^M`.  What could work would be replacing the mode line with an image spanning two rows and manipulating that as needed...